Getting error when applying check on SQL query
I am writing this SQL query on Databricks SQL notebook
Create or replace table student 
(
Student_id int primary key,
Age int check ( age>10)
)

But getting an error

[Parse syntax Error ]: syntax error at or near check


SQL Server <> MySQL; which are you really using?

Side note, Age is not something you want to store, as people's ages change. Their date of birth does not.

Remove or replace from your query.
Valid SQL Query:
Create table student  ( Student_id int primary key, Age int check ( Age>10) );

reference: https://www.programiz.com/sql/check#:~:text=The%20syntax%20of%20the%20SQL,the%20table%20to%20be%20created
Alternative way, you may write:
drop table if exists student;

Create  table student 
(
Student_id int primary key,
Age int check ( Age>10)
);

Sample Code: db<>fiddle

Why shouldn't they use CREATE OR REPLACE?

CREATE OR REPLACE not work for SQL Table, it work for SQL View.
more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html
@Jonas Metzler

Your url links to a documentation about MySQL, but OP taged Databricks

Someone removed MySQL tag. It was previously in this question... That's why I did...
